# How to get scroll position and document height then run a function and update document height again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, locomotivejs, locomotive-scroll

My document height is 11886 and scroll position when I scroll to the bottom of the document is 9542.

I have a function I want to run when I scroll to the bottom of the document that will increase the size of the document again and load in more content. I then need to update the document height and allow the user to keep scrolling down.

When I reach the bottom again I want to run the function and update the document height.

Using [Locomotive.js](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) scroll.
Const scroll is creating the scroll functionality.

```
(function () {
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
        el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
        smooth: true,
        class: 'aos-animate',
    });

    $(window).on("load", function () {
        scroll.update();
    });


   
        let height = $(document).height();
        console.log(height);

        scroll.on('scroll', (position) => {
            // let scroll_position = position.scroll.y;
            // console.log(scroll_position);
            const pageHeight = $('body').height() - $(window).height();
            let scrollPos = position.scroll.y;
            let scrollPercentage = (scrollPos * 100) / pageHeight;
            let finalPercentage = Math.ceil(scrollPercentage);

            console.log(finalPercentage);


            if(finalPercentage == 100) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    my_repeater_show_more();
                    scroll.update();
                    $('.mouse-follow').each(function (index, el) {
                        var html = $(this).data('content');
                        $(el).mousefollow({
                            html: html,
                            className: 'js-follow',
                        });
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
        })
    })
})();
```

Comment: I have some questions, 1. is expected pageHeight value really obtainable by substracting body.height with window.height ? 2. Have you tried using value of window.scroll instead of scroll value from scroll.on() ?

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to calculate a percentage of scroll position in relation to the total page height. Then when that percentage reaches 100%, to call the method that loads more content; an infinite scroll effect.

Try using the `document.documentElement` properties on your scroll event listener to get the `scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight` values.

Try using this to calculate the percentage in your scroll event listener:

```
const {scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight} = document.documentElement;
const finalPercentage = Math.round((scrollTop + clientHeight) / scrollHeight * 100);
```

The snippet below is an example showing how you can generate new pages when the `finalPercentage` reaches 100.

```js
const qs = selector => document.querySelector(selector);
const height = Math.round(document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2);
const width = Math.round(document.documentElement.clientWidth / 3) - 15;
let currentPage = 1;

function addPage() {
  const pageContent = document.createElement(`div`);
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    pageContent.innerHTML += `
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/${width}x${height}.png?text=Page ${currentPage}">`;
  }
  pageContent.innerHTML += `<hr>`
  qs(`main`).appendChild(pageContent);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const {scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight} = document.documentElement;
  const finalPercentage = Math.round((scrollTop + clientHeight) / scrollHeight * 100);
  if (finalPercentage == 100) {
    currentPage++;
    addPage();
  }
},{ passive: true });

addPage();
```

```html
<main />
```